# Spring injects constructor arg while it's not passed in the xml

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on an application that uses both XML and spring boot. There is a class that is not annotated as `Service` or `Component`, etc. Nor its constructor is annotated with `@Autowired`.

This class is defined in a xml as a bean and the args are defined as separate beans in the same xml, but one of the beans (although being defined in that xml) is not passed to this bean as `constructor-arg`. But the bean is still created, and it works.

I know since Spring 4.3 there is no need to annotate `@Autowired` the constructors of classes with with only one constructor. But this class is not annotated with Service or Component either.

How does Spring figure that missing constructor out?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.